# How to configure apache so that only one organizational unit from windows server has access to the page

Tags: linux, windows, apache-2.4

Im trying to configure ldap on apache in rocky linux but i want to allow only the users that belong to the group ITGeral from Win server to have access to the page. how do i configure that? i will leave here my configuration so far

Listen 41414 https <VirtualHost *:41414>

```
        ServerAdmin     webmail@soitezes.local
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/www.soitezes.local"
        Servername      www.soitezes.local
        ServerAlias     www.soitezes.local
        <Directory /var/www/www.soitezes.local>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride none
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AuthType basic
                AuthBasicProvider ldap
                AuthName "Digite o username e a password como faz no login do windows"
                AuthUserFile "/dev/null"
                AuthLdapURL "ldap://10.48.70.1:389/DC=seunome,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
                AuthLdapBindDN "plinha@seunome.local"
                AuthLdapBindPassword    "Passw0rd"
                AuthLdapGroupAttribute on
                Require ldap-group CN=jcalhau,OU=Angola,DC=seunome,DC=local,DC=Formacao
        </Directory>

ErrorLog logs/www.soitezes.local_error_log
Transferlog logs/www.soitezes.local_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/www.soitezes.local.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/www.soitezes.local.key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

Comment: In the Subject you state, that you want to limit the access to an OU, but your question refers to a group. Please rephrase and clarify. Also consider to add some more detail regarding configuration and used modules.

Comment: Hi, if from a group, thats inside of an OU